# Handling remote (RDP) mouse clicking via Python

Tags: python, automation, remote-desktop, pyautogui, rdp

I am using pyautogui to automate some mouse clicking in a script that I created.

This script needs to perform one click to log into a program, nothing else (besides other non-clicking stuff). The idea is that the script will run on a remote Win10 PC via a task scheduler every day at, lets say, at 11PM.

My script works perfectly when run on my own PC but I am running into issues with how to handle the remote RDP resolution to correctly identify the mouse position to click. Furthermore, the script will run on a remote PC that might not have "active user" logged in and I am not even sure if this mouse clicking approach will work. How to identify correctly the "resolution" of the remote PC?

Could you help me?

Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

Pyautogui can be used to interact with remote system the same way a human can by opening the RDP or VNC window identifying elements inside of it and then directly interacting with them. This works but you're now expecting two systems to be in sufficiently consistent state for the automation to work. This does have the advantage that you don't need to know the resolution of the remote system just what the interactable elements look like when rendered through the RDP client on your system.

Comment: I have now figured out that pyautogui does not support "headless" operations with remote PCs. Therefore, I cannot use pyautogui without having an external monitor attached to the PC. I was thinking about using a virtual display with PyVirtualDisplay but it is not supported on Windows. Any ideas for a workaround? :)

Comment: I'd strongly suggest exploring your options for directly scripting whatever app you're needing to interact with, without interacting with it's GUI. Having worked providing support for a production Pyautogui system it's incredibly susceptible to minor environment changes. It's great if you want to hack something together quick but it's not something I'd want to rely on long term.

Comment: Unfortunately that is not an option for me...